# No module named 'playwright.sync_api'; 'playwright' is not a package

Tags: python, playwright

i have install playwright (python) using pip but it's not working giving the following error:
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playwright.sync_api'; 'playwright' is not a package"

i have tried to install it with pip after launching the command line in the script folder itself but also didn't work!

the only way i could run it when i created the file that run it into the "script foulder"
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts. and it will not work form any other directory.

Comment: You might have some file sitting in the folder called `playwright.py` which is messing up the import.

Comment: Maybe share a screenshot or a description of your setup/files for people to help you.

Comment: Better yet, you can share it [as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)